# Complex Conditional Matching and Marking in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Question:**

I'm working on a Python project that involves manipulating a dataset in a Pandas DataFrame. I need to implement conditional matching based on values from the "Big List", "Small List", and "Status" columns. Here's a detailed breakdown of the process.

I'm now working on the this step, and I'm seeking assistance in implementing the following logic:

a. Find a value in the "Big List" column.

b. Compare the matched value with the corresponding value in the "Small List" column.

c. If they match, search again for the matched value in the "Big List" column.

d. Compare the new matched value with the corresponding value in the "Status" column.

e. If the value in the "Status" column is "B", search the "Big List" column again to find a duplicates of the initial matched value.

f. If the duplicates's status is "P" or "F", mark the corresponding cell in the "Match" column as "OK"; otherwise, mark it as "Not OK" in the same row.

**Here's a simplified example of the dataset:**

| Big List | Status | Small list | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | P |  |  |
| 2 | B | 2 |  |
| 15 | P |  |  |
| 17 | F |  |  |
| 30 | B | 30 |  |
| 47 | B |  |  |
| 2 | P |  |  |
| 45 | F |  |  |

**Expected result:**

| Big List | Status | Small list | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | P |  |  |
| 2 | B | 2 | OK |
| 15 | P |  |  |
| 17 | F |  |  |
| 30 | B | 30 | Not OK |
| 47 | B |  |  |
| 2 | P |  |  |
| 45 | F |  |  |

I'm stuck on implementing the loop logic in Step 2 and conditionals to achieve the desired "Match" outcomes. Here's my starting code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Big List': [10, 2, 15, 17, 30, 40, 30, 47, 50,55], 
        'Status':['P','B','P','F','B','B','P','P','B','F'],
        'Small List': [17, 15, 42, 31, 45, 30]}

# Loop through rows and compare values
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Small List'] in df['Big List']:
        # Sort the row in the "Small List" column
        # Stuck here
    else:
        # Add value to "Not Matched" column
        # Stuck here

print(df)
```

Any help, suggestions, or code examples on implementing the conditional matching logic for this loop would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, since you have solved the first part why show it, it is not a part of the problem.  Start with the an example output of the of step 1, explain what you are trying to accomplish and show an example.  As written, your question is too confusing, for me

Comment: I have reduced my question and modified the script.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use :

```
d = (
    df.loc[~df["Big List"].duplicated(keep="last")]
      .set_index("Big List")["Status"].isin(["P", "F"])
      .replace({True: "OK", False: "Not OK"}).to_dict()
)

# {10: 'OK', 15: 'OK', 17: 'OK', 30: 'Not OK', 47: 'Not OK', 2: 'OK', 45: 'OK'}


df["Match"] = df["Small list"].map(d)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   Big List Status  Small list   Match
0        10      P         NaN     NaN
1         2      B         2.0      OK
2        15      P         NaN     NaN
3        17      F         NaN     NaN
4        30      B        30.0  Not OK
5        47      B         NaN     NaN
6         2      P         NaN     NaN
7        45      F         NaN     NaN
```

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Big List": [10, 2, 15, 17, 30, 47, 2, 45],
    "Status": ["P", "B", "P", "F", "B", "B", "P", "F"],
    "Small list": [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 30, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    }
)
```

Comment: How can i add the empty places with np.nan at first? And where ist the Condition with "B" in column "Status" in the code?
→ (e. If the value in the "Status" column is "B", search the "Big List" column again to find a duplicate of the initial matched value.)

Comment: Search for a value in the "Big List" and "Small List". Is there a match?→ If yes, examine the value in the "Status" column of the matching row. If the value is "B", → search again in the "Big List" to find duplicates. If the value of all duplicate found is "P" or "F", the result is "is ok". If not, the result is "not ok".